# In ITHit WebDAV server how do I make it use the CORS allowed origins list configured in startup.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ithit-webdav-server

When using ITHit WebDAV server it applies its own CORS settings, this is OK for the Verbs and Methods in my case. However it only allows on to configure one Origin, in my case I have multiple origins I need to support. So is it possible to make ITHit use the origin settings that is configured on an application level without it overwriting it?

Comment: Mind to go a step back and to explain why you'd need CORS on a WebDAV at all and your setup??! WebDAV is a protocol for kinda web drives (similar to a share) and how the ASP.NET Core application fits in there? Is ITHit a middleware for ASP.NET Core? If so would placing the Cors middleware before it work?

Comment: The reason why I ask is, usually you don't access the WebDAV via JavaScript (which is the only place where CORS is applied) but either via native WebDAV clients (CORS doesn't apply) or directly access it via browsers URL (again, no CORS in here). Sounds like an odd setup and kind of an abuse of what WebDAV is meant for (WebDAV is not meant to act as an webserver but as a kind of network share)

Comment: I see that you are not familiar with the company or product in the question. You can read up on it here https://www.webdavsystem.com/

Comment: The company or the product are pretty irrelevant. WebDAV is a protocol, and its meant as a kind of network share and I can't imagine reasons why you would want to access a WebDAV from JavaScript (since only for JavaScript CORS is required/necessary). So you'd need to explain your use case, since it appears to be a classic case of [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/392095)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating my own middleware that adds/replaces the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header on the response after it has passed the ItHit middleware, with the Origin from the request if valid. If the request is invalid is still up in the air as there are multiple flavors on how to deal with it, for now i just send a 403 without processing the request.

I hope IT Hit will do an update to not roll their own implementation and use the native one part of Asp.Net Core.